# Git blame command to get list between two dates

Tags: git, git-blame

Git gives since option

```
git blame --since=3.weeks -- foo
```

Is there a way I can get the blame list between two date?
That is: something similar to `git log --since` and `--until`.

Answer (score 2):

> similar to git log since and until

That [was discussed here in 2017](https://public-inbox.org/git/1503254759.3881.9.camel@gmail.com/t/).

First, [`git blame`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame) takes options that are fed to [`git rev-list`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list), to limit the
commits being taken into account for blaming.

And `git rev-list` does have:

```
-until=<date>
--before=<date>
```

> Show commits older than a specific date.

So these options are not documented under `git blame`, but `git rev-list`.

BUT: said options are *ignored* by `git blame`.

Ie, `git blame --since=3.weeks --before=2.weeks  -- foo` would not "error", but... would silently ignore the `--before=2.weeks` part.

---

Junio C Hamano comments (speaking about commits, but that applies to dates too):

> Many options that `rev-list` takes are parsed but then ignored by `blame`, simply because they do not make much sense in the context of the command, and "`--before`" is one of them.
>
> It is interesting to realize that "`--since`" (and its synonym "`--after`") does make sense, unlike "`--before`" (and its synonym "`--until`") which does not.
>
> Let's imagine a history like this (time flows from left to right):
>
> ```
> --c1--c2--c4--c6--c8--c9
>         \         /
>          c3--c5--c7
> ```
>
> where the tip of the history is at commit "`c9`", and the number in
>   the name of each commit denotes its timestamp.
>
> - "`git rev-list c9`" starts from "`c9`", and follows the chain of parents and would produce `c9`, `c8`, `c7`, `c6`, ..., `c1`, ....
> - If you add "`--after 2`", i.e. "`git rev-list --after 2 c9`" does exactly the same traversal as the above, but stops following the chain of parents for commits that is earlier than the specified time.
> - If you add "`--before 6`", i.e. "`git rev-list --before 6 c9`" does exactly the same traversal as the first one, but does not show the commit whose timestamp is later than the specified time.
>     It would be like saying "`git rev-list c5 c6`" in the above topology; the traversal from `c9` down to `c5` and `c6` is done only to find `c5` and `c6` to start the "real" traversal from.
>
> Now, "`--after 2`" will still show "`c9`", the tip you start your traversal from, and this is important in the context of "`blame`".
>
> Unlike "`git rev-list`" (and "`git log`" family of commands), **which can take more than one positive endpoints in the history** (e.g. it is perfectly sensible to ask "`git log -p ^c1 c5 c6 -- myfile`" in the example topology above), **"`git blame`" must be given exactly one positive endpoint**, as "`git blame ^c1 c5 c6 -- myfile`" would *not* make any sense (ask: "do we want to know about `myfile` in `c5`?  or `myfile` in `c6`?").